# Django3.x - Heroku - raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-deployment

I need your help colleagues. I am trying to deploy my Django Project on Heroku but I am getting a seemingly simple error but I have struggled to debug it for days. I would appreciate detailed help, I am a newbie. Thanking you in advance.

**Background** I have hidden foldername because it is also a domainname I want to register.
I have python 3.6.8 and Django 2.1.1 on a windows10 machine and Heroku PaaS. At first I was using Django 2.2 then downgraded to Django 2.1. by command `pipenv install djang0==2.1.1`
Project works perfectly on local/development server i.e `python manage runserver` works .
The secret key is set `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET')`, I have also tried hard coding `SECRET_KEY = 'my-secret-key'` but no difference.
I have `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '*foldername.settings.testing')` correctly set in wsgi.py & manage.py

**Other Settings**
My Procfile for Heroku has `web: gunicorn *foldername.wsgi:application --log-file -`. I have a `requirements` and a `runtime.txt` files.

**Error** When I run `$ heroku run python manage.py migrate`

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ thawing-thicket-02648... up, run.2948 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 22, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 87, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Running `$ heroku logs --tail` produces

```
2020-01-29T15:56:40.652606+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-01-29T15:56:40.652609+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-01-29T15:56:40.652893+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-01-29T15:56:40.652896+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-01-29T15:56:40.745655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-01-29T15:56:40.725433+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-01-29T16:21:03.239311+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user developers@email.com
2020-01-29T16:21:11.782005+00:00 heroku[run.2948]: State changed from starting to up
2020-01-29T16:21:11.639515+00:00 heroku[run.2948]: Awaiting client
2020-01-29T16:21:11.664869+00:00 heroku[run.2948]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2020-01-29T16:21:16.264816+00:00 heroku[run.2948]: State changed from up to complete
2020-01-29T16:21:16.241764+00:00 heroku[run.2948]: Process exited with status 1
2020-01-29T16:23:33.250194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-01-29T16:23:39.991409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn foldername.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-01-29T16:23:42.075462+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-01-29T16:23:42.076104+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:34607 (4)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.076210+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-01-29T16:23:42.080161+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-01-29T16:23:42.131810+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302136+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302140+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302160+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302163+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302165+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302167+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302169+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302171+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302173+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302176+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302178+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302180+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302182+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302184+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302186+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302188+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302190+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302193+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302195+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302197+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302199+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302201+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302203+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302205+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302207+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/foldername/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302209+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302211+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302213+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302215+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302217+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302219+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302221+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302224+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302226+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302228+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302230+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302240+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
2020-01-29T16:23:42.302620+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322533+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322537+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322539+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322542+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322544+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322545+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322547+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322549+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322552+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322554+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322556+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322558+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322560+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322562+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322564+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322566+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322568+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322570+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322572+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322574+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322576+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322578+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322580+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322582+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322584+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/foldername/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322586+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322590+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322592+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322594+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322596+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322598+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322600+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322602+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322604+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322606+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322609+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
2020-01-29T16:23:42.322958+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-01-29T16:23:42.449777+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-01-29T16:23:42.469241+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29 16:23:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-01-29T16:23:42.572344+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-01-29T16:23:42.557638+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
```

Normal `$ python manage.py migrate` without `heroku run` part does the migrations but app still won't start and error trace back from `$ heroku logs --tail` still present and the same

[See my folder structure & wsgi.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wztj8.jpg)

[See my manage.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za6y2.jpg)

[Settings just to show secret key is in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGr1z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Long time has passed but if I had seen this I would have saved a couple hours. I had the same issue as I had forgot to set the SECRET_KEY variable in the Heroku config vars.